# Accessing Resources in Swift PlaygroundBook

Tags: swift, swift-playground, xcplayground

I am having trouble accessing images which I have stored in a sub directory in the PrivateResources Folder of my Swift Playgroundbook.  I'm trying to access the following images. I have tried `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "img_1", ofType: "jpg", inDirectory: "trainingSample/0")`, `Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "jpg", subdirectory: "trainingSample/0")`, and `Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: "trainingSample", ofType: nil)` but they all return either empty arrays or nil. Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance! [image: images I'm trying to access]